# Rebuilding historical builds through TFS with version numbers

Tags: tfs, msbuild

I have automatic build numbering setup, based on build date/name, using approach proposed by John Robbins from Wintellect described [here](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2009/11/09/tfs-2010-build-number-and-assembly-file-versions-completely-in-sync-with-only-msbuild-4-0.aspx). So the version/resource file is automatically created on build time but not checked-in.
I wonder how to approach a problem of rebuilding historical versions (based on labels) and having the original build number/name in them. Is it possible to detect 'GetVersion' parameter of MSBuild and try to recreate the original build name from it?
Is it a sane approach anyway? What alternatives do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not easy to build a specific changeset (though possible, if you pass the changeset number into your build script and modify the "Get Latest" portion of the build).

However, one easier way of handling this is to create a branch of your code.  You can branch at a specific date or changeset, which will create a copy of code from that point in time.  Your build scripts can then be pointed at this code.

With respect to your versioning problem: you may find that the only sensible way to do this is to hardcode the required version number.  My understanding of your version numbering strategy is that it doesn't relate to anything you can derive from the source (such as the changeset number, date, or file content), and it isn't checked in - so re-calculating it will be pretty complicated!

Comment: The branching approach is what I'd recommend. You can never be really certain which versions are actually selected using changeset versions or labels the way TFS works. Branches are cheap and exact though

Comment: @tbergstedt could you provide some link to description of this changeset/label behavior? it really sounds like a major problem for someone trying to go back to previous version

Comment: Here's a short explanation: _"...the label does not represent a point in time, but rather a collection of points in time.  This makes it very hard to display it in a list mixed with change sets because there is not “correct” ordering of the list.  As a result we treat the list of changesets and the list of labels separately."_ From http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2005/11/18/494439.aspx

Comment: @dan-puzey Solution with branching on build seems very nice but i'm little bit concerned about a mess it will create in repository - do you have some recipe to keep it tamed? Also it would be very nice if the branch was create when build reaches certain quality - can this be automated as well?

Comment: Auto-branch on build should be very much doable with the `tf branch` command, e.g. `tf branch dev ..\builds\2011-08-22 /noget`. And making it dependent on quality should simply be a matter of putting the branch command as late as possible, right?

But I'd be very strict with this; there's a high risk of getting swamped in branches - they are cheap but not free, if you get my meaning. I'd use some logic to only keep the last succesful build within a release, or something like that.

Comment: You could also try a "branching from label" scenario, and simply label results upon (successful) builds to be used for branching/rebuilding later on when needed. I know I'm a bit contradictive here, but the point is to find the cheapest way that still gives you the expected results

Answer (score -1):

You ask question Rebuilding historical builds but it actually Rebuilding historical change Set or label, I know what you mean but I am trying to tell you what I need to say, so I don't see that we need to build a label with the specific name the label or change set can has many build as needed and since we use the date and time in the build number it will more realistic to has the current time and date the build was taken instead of old one

Thanks

M.Radwan

Comment: Could you rewrite your answer to include more than one sentence?  I'm not sure it makes a huge amount of sense!